# Manjaro Linux snort installation : ERROR! dnet header not found

Tags: linux, arch-linux, manjaro, snort

I want to install snort on Manjaro Linux. snort is not available on pacman and I tried to install via code below.

```
pamac build snort
```

I am getting this error

```
ERROR!  dnet header not found, go get it from
   http://code.google.com/p/libdnet/ or use the --with-dnet-*
   options, if you have it installed in an unusual place
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
```

libdnet is already installed on my system. 
Maybe I need to install snort via download from its official website but i don't know where is libdnet libraries and includes to give parameter to ./configure

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by manually removing libdnet files from /usr/local/

Another problem I encounter is when trying to run snort

```
ERROR: Can't find pcap DAQ!
```

I solved this second problem with the code below

```
sudo snort --daq-dir /usr/lib/daq/
```